# Which query in database is better?

Tags: sql, database

suppose to I have one table and filter by type like wordpress database
// general table

```
id | title | content | type
---------------------------
1  | hello | some... | post
---------------------------
2  | image | con     | image

select * post where type = post
```

or

// table post

```
id | title | content 
--------------------
1  | hello | some...
select * post
```

//table image

```
id | title | content 
---------------------
2  | image | con      

select * image
```

so I mean that if I make more table is better or make a single table for my database?

Answer (score 4):

The idea in database design is to have one table per "entity" -- hence the name, "entity-relationship modeling".

It seems reasonable to think that "images" and "posts" are quite different things and should go into their own tables.

That does not mean that "more tables are better".  It means that "the appropriate tables are best".  In particular, it is generally a bad idea to split an entity across multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to have table per business entity. Business keeps on changing in future, and thus it becomes hard to maintain data in single table. So Posts and Image should be 2 tables. No second thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

the multi table in large project and for small project the general table is better